# ALT Enable not working

Tags: media

I've created some Content type which contains few image field. It works fine for me, but I decided to add alt field. I've simply edit field and checked ALT Enable checkbox. Sadly it makes no difference. I know that ALT input field should appear below image input, but nothing is there. This same with other Image fields. I'm using drupal 7 and Seven theme for administration pages. I've also tried to check TITLE Enabled checkbox and it also not working. I Don't know what may cause this.

Comment: It could be an issue in the theme. Change to some other theme and check. If you still face the issue do a dpm($form) and check if the alt value form element is present.

Comment: try clearing the cache

Comment: I cleared cache few times, after change in every content type field.

Comment: It's not theme issue. Same on bartik.